# My work directory in ModelSim is always empty. How can I resolve this problem?

Tags: verilog, modelsim

I'm new to Verilog. I made a new ModelSim project and kept the default directory to work. Then I added .v (Verilog) files to the project. And after that I compiled the files. Compilation was successful. But even after that my work library is empty.

I don't know what changed, as previously I followed the similar procedure and files were added in work directory. Is this some problem of path/logical mapping?

I tried reinstalling the software, but the problem is the same. The following is the image after successful compilation of the software:

[image: screenshot of ModelSim windows]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has nothing to do with electrical engineering

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. I installed a different software MODELSIM ALTERA STARTER EDITION (from Intel's Website).

Thanks